# Specific Heat Ratio for a perfect gas mixture

Tags: physics, chemistry, rocket-equation, thermodynamics

I am reading *Rocket Propulsion Elements by George P. Sutton & Oscar Biblarz, 9th Edition*. In the fifth chapter, I was introduce to the specific heat ratio k for the perfect gas mixture, Eq. 5-7:

(1) $k_{\text{mix}} = \frac{(C_{p})_{\text{mix}}}{(C_{p})_{\text{mix}}-R'}$

Since,

(2) $k_{j} = \frac{(C_{p})_{\text{j}}}{(C_{v})_{\text{j}}}$

(3) $R_{j} = \frac{R'}{\mathfrak{M}_{j}} $ $\text{&}$

(4) $R_{j} = (C_{p})_{\text{j}} - (C_{v})_{\text{j}}$

It seems to me that this equation should instead include the mixture gas constant $R_{\text{mix}}$ in the place of the Universal gas constant, $R'$.

I tried to derive it without success. Can someone clarify this to me?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be a bad one, however, I believe it is not really suited for this site... For chemistry questions, check out https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On topic here, on topic on chemistry (or physics?). OP decides where to post in that case. And OP posted here.

Comment: Good question and congrats on going through the details. My 4th edition doesn't have these equations in it. And I learned something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal gas constant R' is correct. Sutton uses $C_p$ for molar specific heat and $c_p$ for mass specific heat. See table of symbols at end of chapter (I have the 7th ed.).

Comment: Since $C_{p}$ is the molar specific heat, my mistake is equation (4). It should be:             
 $R' = (C_{p}) - (C_{v})$